# How do you print words with a bit of time between letters? (Python)

Tags: python

The code that I wrote here (I'm just assuming) should print the letters with a little time between each letter, as if someone was typing:

```
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

def timedPrint(string, time):
    array = list(string)
    for x in array:
        stdout.write(x)
        sleep(time)

timedPrint("test")
```

But for some reason, when I call the function, it waits the time it takes for every character to print, then prints the entire string ("test").

Is there a way to have it print as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to flush `stdout` after writing each character:

```
for x in array:
    stdout.write(x)
    stdout.flush()  # <--
    sleep(time)
```

Answer (score 1):

try `sys.stdout.flush()` in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

by the way, your code will return error because you only supply timedPrint with 1 arguments. it should be

```
timedPrint("test",1)
```

to print each one second. By the way, there is no problem if you run this code using command line

```
python something.py
```

The result will be exactly what you need. But what happens is maybe you run this under certain IDE or editor. What may happens there is because you do the sleep() function under main thread. if the IDE also have their own console rendering, it's possible that the sleep() function which is run under main thread also suspend the console renderer in your IDE. try to put it under new thread it should work fine whatever is your IDE or editor

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
import time

def slowPrint(str, t):
  for l in str:
    print l,
    time.sleep(t)
```

or this:

```
import time
from sys import stdout
def slowPrint(str, t):
    for l in str:
        stdout.write(l)
        stdout.flush()
        time.wait(t)
```

the code is untested but should work if you use tabs instead of 4 spaces ;)